# Why is ERC-5185 in "Stagnant" status?

Tags: nft, erc-721, erc-1155, meta-data, assets

I work for a gaming company and we are looking for options to managing mutable metadata for in-game assets.

I would like to use [ERC-5185](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-5185) to implement this.

Does anybody know why it is in that status? Does this mean it won't continue?

Comment: You are welcome to use it and nobody is stopping you. If you want to have other people and interoperable systems use it, you can build a few examples and/or revive that ERC get it the finish line.

Comment: I was asking because the "Stagnant" status states that "This EIP had no activity for at least 6 months. This EIP should not be used".

Comment: Understood. That wording is suboptimal and we should change it. Please consider it instead to say "... this EIP should not be relied upon as being accurate, best practice, or supporting interoperability with other systems." (You are welcome to PR that and reference this comment). But if you don't care about those guarantees you are still welcome to use it.

Comment: IMO, the EIP could be improved by storing the log trace of updates off-chain in an immutable way, using arweave or pinata. Ethereum nodes are no longer required to store the full history of the blockchain, and these updates could easily be stored off-chain using for example an append-only linked list of update files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an EIP is in "Stagnant" status it means that it has been inactive for at least 6 months and the recommendation is not to use it.